# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Also trim and strip is not a function

Tags: javascript

There is code:

```js
function Hours(days){
  weekHours = 0;
  for(i = 0; i != days.length; i++){
    if(days[i].length > 3){
      dayHours = days[i].trim().split('-');
      weekHours += parseFloat(dayHours[1]) - parseFloat(dayHours[0]);
    }
  }
  return weekHours;
}

var fruits = [" 8-16  ",    " 8-23 ",   " 17-23 ",  " 16-23 ",  " 8-16 ", " 12-18 ",    " В "];

console.log(Hours(fruits));
```

Why i have this errors:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

TypeError: days[i].trim is not a function

TypeError: days[i].strip is not a function

Comment: This code works fine; are you sure you're running the code you think you are? You would not see separate errors for `days[i].trim` *and* `days[i].strip` with this code since they're chained.

Comment: I don't know for sure but try changing your for Like this: i < days.length or try logging your i to see if its going more than your array.length or not

Comment: Wondering though he has added `if(days[i].length > 3)` this check, then if the array has undefined or null it shouldn't throw an error. Need some more information for sure. I agree with @DaveNewton +1

Comment: I just run the code it works fine like @DaveNewton said.

Answer (score 0):

It's acting as if an undefined or null is in your `fruits` array.  Did you have an extra comma in it originally, because the code works fine as-is.

Meaning,

`var fruits = ['8-16',' B '];` is fine but

`var fruits = ['8-16',,' B '];` is not.

Comment: `var fruits = ['8-16',]` is fine.

Comment: Because `trim` isn't a function that exists on its own, it's a method on `String.prototype`. Trailing commas in arrays are fine.